# Can't send data to localStorage in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage

I try to build an app in React with Redux and i try to get data from my Redux store and send the data to my localStorage but I have a little problem because my data in localStorage is saved like:

```
data    [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

[image]

This is how i get and send data to my localStorage:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

function Table() {
    const myUsers = useSelector((state) => state.users.data);

    function test() {
        let data = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < myUsers.length; i++) {
            data.push(myUsers[i]);
        }

        localStorage.setItem('data', data);
    }

    test();


    return (
        <div>Table</div>
    )
}

export default Table
```

My database:

```
const database = [
    {
        id: 1,
        email: "email1@gmail.com",
        birthYear: "1999",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        email: "email2@gmail.com",
        birthYear: "1987",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        email: "email3@gmail.com",
        birthYear: "2005",
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        email: "email4@gmail.com",
        birthYear: "1967",
    },
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: When you load the data from localstorage, you'll have to run JSON.parse

Comment: Thank you very much. I will upvote it in 15 mins when I will can

Comment: This is an ***often*** repeated duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/how-to-store-objects-in-html5-localstorage. There's no need to have yet another copy of those answers here.

Answer (score -1):

localstorage doesnt allow objects but only strings to be stored in them. so convert your array into string by `JSON.stringify()` and then store it using `localStorage.setItem()` or `localStorage.getItem()` an while getting the array use `JSON.parse()`
To Set

```
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data))
```

To Get

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data))
```

Comment: This is an ***often*** repeated duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/how-to-store-objects-in-html5-localstorage. There's no need to have yet another copy of those answers here.